# doctrine2 findby two columns OR condition

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

My action:

```
   $matches_request = $em->getRepository('Bundle:ChanceMatch')->findByRequestUser(1);
   $matches_reply = $em->getRepository('Bundle:ChanceMatch')->findByReplyUser(1);
```

Is it possible to join the querys with an `or` condition with getRepository, eg.

```
$matches_reply = $em->getRepository('FrontendChancesBundle:ChanceMatch')->findBy(array('requestUser' => 1, 'replyUser' => 1); 
//this of course gives me the a result when `requestUser` and `replyUser` is `1`.
```

My table

```
id | requestUser | replyUser
....
12 |      1      |     2
13 |      5      |     1
```

My query should return the `id 12 & 13`.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use QueryBuilder or create a custom repository for that entity and create a function that internally use QueryBuilder.

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('FrontendChancesBundle:ChanceMatch')->createQueryBuilder('cm');
$qb
    ->select('cm')
    ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('cm.requestUser', ':requestUser'),
        $qb->expr()->eq('cm.replyUser', ':replyUser')
    ))
    ->setParameter('requestUser', $requestUserId)
    ->setParameter('replyUser', $replyUserId)
;
$matches_reply = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
// $matches_reply = $qb->getQuery()->getResult(); // use this if there can be more than one result
```

For more information on custom Repository see official documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use `Criteria` for the complex queries with `getRepository()`:

```
$criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
$criteria
  ->orWhere($criteria->expr()->contains('domains', 'a'))
  ->orWhere($criteria->expr()->contains('domains', 'b'));

$domain->ages = $em
  ->getRepository('Group')
  ->matching($criteria);
```