# Doctrine findBy or statement

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have problem with my doctrine `findBy` method. I know how to do in doctrine

```
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE Z = 1 OR Z = 2 OR Z = 3
```

But I don't know how to do

```
SELECT * FROM Y WHERE Z = 10 OR Y = 10 OR X = 10
```

I must add that I don't want to do this in querybuilder, only in this way:
`findBy(array(1=> "aaa"))`. Is it possible?

Greetings!

Comment: if you look into the findBy method of Doctrine (and follow it through) you can see that you can set a Criteria() along the way... which is basically what you are trying to do. BUT: don't do it. Create a Repository Class for your Entity and put your own findBy method in there doing what you need. Best practice and faster/easier to implement.

Comment: What do you think about do 3 times findby and in the next step merge arrays ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15232028/1348344).

To be specific about your use case:

```
$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository('YourEntityClassName')
    ->createQueryBuilder('c');

$result = $queryBuilder->select('c')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('c.x', ':value'),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('c.y', ':value'),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('c.z', ':value')
    ))
    ->setParameter('value', 10)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Or simple:

```
$queryBuilder = $em->getRepository('YourEntityClassName')
    ->createQueryBuilder('c');

$result = $queryBuilder->select('c')
    ->where('c.x = :value or c.y = :value or c.z = :value')
    ->setParameter(':value', 10)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
```

`$queryBuilder->expr()` is here only to prevent typos and make your code more futureproof, since it's wrapped in methods.

---

It's possible with `findBy()` via Criteria, yet difficult and not well documented, as pointed out by [@Cedar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347653/doctrine-findby-or-statement/33351381?noredirect=1#comment54503531_33351381).

Comment: Thank you Tomas for your answer. I had hope that i can do this only with findBy :) I have my queryBuilder syntax like :
"$this->em->getRepository('myRep')->createQueryBuilder('c')->where('c.x = :var or c.y = :var or c.z = :var ')->setParameter(':var', 100)->getQuery()->getResult();"
It also works :)

Comment: Yea, it's unfortunate, but the `findBy()` method only covers basic usage. I'm glad you found your solution.

Comment: Thank you Tomas,
Greeting for You  !

Comment: Thank you to Juri! I've also updated answer with your solution and explanation for `expr()` method.

Comment: While it is good that this answer solves the problem I should point out that it is indeed possible to create a custom criteria object and use findBy.  It's just not worth the effort nor is there much documentation on the subject.  So the first sentence in the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Cerad: Thanks for sharing the knowledge. I'll update the answer.