# How to use with Doctrine the OR function when having multiple fields?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I'm making an inlog form where the user can decide to use this username or email address in combination with its password. So normally it would something like: ((username OR email) AND password) in SQL. Used the following controller code only don't know how to add the OR function.

```
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('Bundle:CusUser')
            ->findOneBy(
                array('username' => $user->getUsername(), 'email' => $user->getUsername(), 'password' => $user->getPassword())
            );
```

For both is getUsername used as this is the flied in the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [doctrine2 findby two columns OR condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229609/doctrine2-findby-two-columns-or-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no `->orBy(...)` method in the default doctrine `EntityRepository`.
You can find all methods available in the [API](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html) of this class.

Instead, use a `QueryBuilder`:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('Bundle:CusUser')
    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('u')
    ->where('u.username = :username')
    ->orWhere('u.email = :email')
    ->setParameter('username', $user->getUsername())
    ->setParameter('email', $user->getEmail())
    ->getQuery();

// Get the first result
$user = $query->setMaxResults(1)->getSingleResult();
```

Put it in a custom `EntityRepository` and use it with an array of arguments that you use as `where` and `orWhere` statement's parameters. e.g. :

```
public function findByOrBy(array $parameters)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    // ...

    foreach ($parameters as $property => $value) {
        $query
            ->orWhere($property.' = :'.$property)
            ->setParameter($property, $value)
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can find the list of the available methods (almost all correspondences of native SQL methods) in the [`QueryBuilder` API](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html).

Comment: OP should also have a look at the [Expr class](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class). Gives much more flexibility when combining ANDs and ORs.

Answer (score 0):

FOSUserBundle has a similar function to allow user to log in using email or username.

They simply check if the user input is an email or not :

From [friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Model/UserManager.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php#L102) on line 102

```
/**
 * Finds a user either by email, or username
 *
 * @param string $usernameOrEmail
 *
 * @return UserInterface
 */
public function findUserByUsernameOrEmail($usernameOrEmail)
{
    if (filter_var($usernameOrEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return $this->findUserByEmail($usernameOrEmail);
    }

    return $this->findUserByUsername($usernameOrEmail);
}
```

So in you controller you could have this:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    //...

    if (filter_var($usernameOrEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $user = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getRepository('Bundle:CusUser')
            ->findOneBy(array('email' => $usernameOrEmail, 'password' => $password));
    }
    else {
        $user = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getRepository('Bundle:CusUser')
            ->findOneBy(array('username' => $usernameOrEmail, 'password' => $password));
    }

    //...

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: FOSUserBundle use two different queries, how is it related to the second code block?

Comment: Are you sure that `findOneBy()` use `OR` and not `AND`?